# Is this the best way to load existing otherwise create new NSManagedObjects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest

I need to load in a lot of data in through an API and use this to create new or update existing objects and their relationships as we go. Is this the right approach? It seems so long winded, I feel like I am missing something here.

```
// Check for existing Object
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Object" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", objectName]];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (results == nil) {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Error executing fetch: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}

Object *object = [results lastObject];

if (object == nil) {
    // Create new object
    object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Object" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    object.name = objectName;
}


// Check for existing Other
fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Other" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", otherName]];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];

results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (results == nil) {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Error executing fetch: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}

Other *other = [results lastObject];

if (other == nil) {
    // Create new Other
    other = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Other" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    other.name = otherName;
}


// Finally
[object addOtherObject:other]; // A many-to-many relationship

if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}
```

All of this of course being inside a loop, it feels terribly inefficient.

Comment: Have a look at Magical Record and Mogenerator. Core Data is full of boilerplate code, theses libraries remove most of it

Comment: It's all about sets.  Instead of fetching one entity at a time in a loop, fetch all at once.  Then you can figure out which entities don't exist in the results and  create those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to minimize boilerplate.  I have created an `NSManagedObject` subclass that I use as the base for all my model objects.  It contains methods like the following:

```
+ (NSString *)entityName;

+ (instancetype)newEntityInContext:(ManagedObjectContext *)context;
+ (instancetype)newEntityInContext:(ManagedObjectContext *)context properties:(NSDictionary *)properties;

+ (NSArray *)entitiesWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate inContext:(RoundsManagedObjectContext *)context;
+ (NSArray *)entitiesWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
                      sortedBy:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors
                     inContext:(ManagedObjectContext *)context;

+ (NSArray *)entitiesWithProperties:(NSDictionary *)properties inContext:(ManagedObjectContext *)context;

+ (NSInteger)countOfEntitiesWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate inContext:(ManagedObjectContext *)context;
```

I leave it to you to see how these take care of the boilerplate of creating fetch requests and the like.  It really makes your code that actually *uses* core data to be much more readable.

Now, to speak of the efficiency of doing those fetched in a loop:

Don't.  That is, don't do individual fetches.  Instead, gather the `objectName`s into an array and fetch all the related objects at once.  Assuming you implement methods similar to what I wrote above, you can have pseudo-code that looks like this:

```
NSArray *objectNames = ...;
NSArray *otherNames = ...;

NSManagedObjectContext *context = ...;

NSArray *existingObjects = [Object entitiesWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name IN %@", objectNames];
NSArray *existingOthers = [Other entitiesWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name IN %@", otherNames];

NSArray *missingObjectNames = [objectNames removeObjects:[existingObjects valueForKeyPath:@"name"]];

for (NSString *name in missingObjectNames) {
    Object *object = [Object newEntityInContext:context];
    object.name = name;

    // Do stuff with Other objects here.
}
```

Comment: Note: I didn't give code for `Other`, because it's a bit unclear how you determine which `otherName` goes with which `Object`.  Hopefully I've given enough of a basis to figure out what you need to add.